# Отправка telegram-ботом картинки с локального диска

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Можно отправить картинку ботом, указав боту ссылку на источник.
А как можно отправить картинку, которая находится в одной папке с самим ботом?
Спасибо.

P.S.: python, библиотека `telebot`.

Comment: [Пример для бота](https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__url2image_bot/blob/master/main.py#L84) из библиотеки `telegram`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отправлять картинку, которая находится рядом с ботом, на сервере или на локальном компьютере, можно точно так же как и ту, которая уже находится в сети. Только вначале нужно открыть файл на чтение в двоичном режиме, а затем передать его в качестве второго аргумента вместо ссылки.

Вот пример для обоих вариантов.

```
bot.send_photo(ид_получателя, open('/путь/к/картинке.jpg', 'rb'));
bot.send_photo(ид_получателя, 'https://example.org/адрес/картинки.jpg');
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.